# What is the significance of the principal_id in sys.schemas?

Tags: sql-server, schema, users, database-internals, catalogs

What is the meaning of the `principal_id` in `sys.schemas` and when would it ever be different from `schema_id`?

```
1> SELECT LEFT(name,20), schema_id, principal_id FROM sys.schemas;
2> GO
                     schema_id   principal_id
-------------------- ----------- ------------
dbo                            1            1
guest                          2            2
INFORMATION_SCHEMA             3            3
sys                            4            4
db_owner                   16384        16384
db_accessadmin             16385        16385
db_securityadmin           16386        16386
db_ddladmin                16387        16387
db_backupoperator          16389        16389
db_datareader              16390        16390
db_datawriter              16391        16391
db_denydatareader          16392        16392
db_denydatawriter          16393        16393

(13 rows affected)
```

Internally, I see that the `schema_id` comes from `sys.sysclsobjs` while the `principal_id` comes from `sys.syssingleobjrefs`'s `r.indepid` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be the default "owner" of all objects in the schema. Schema-bound objects have a `principal_id` column that is `NULL` by default, in which case it uses the `principal_id` of the Schema that the object is in.

The object owner is used for ownership chaining, and most likely also when determining if rights exist to perform operations that can be done by the object owner or a User in a the `db_owner` Database Role, such as [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql), [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql), etc.

The `principal_id` in `sys.schemas` can be any User if changed via [ALTER AUTHORIZATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql).

If using Schemas for logical separation of objects more than security separation, then it would make sense to use the same `principal_id` across multiple Schemas. For example, executing the following in the `AdventureWorks2012` Database:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas;
```

shows that the following Schemas are all owned by "dbo":

```
dbo
HumanResources
Person
Production
Purchasing
Sales
```

Having the same "owner" across `Sales` and `Purchasing` (and the others) allows ownership chaining to imply permissions of referenced objects within top-level objects. Meaning, if you execute a Stored Procedure in the `Sales` Schema, and it selects from a View in the `Purchasing` Schema, then permissions won't be re-checked and everything just works. But, if you then specify the `principal_id` of the View in the `Purchasing` Schema such that the column is no longer `NULL` (and not the same as the "dbo" User) then it will re-check permissions to see if the User executing the Stored Procedure has `SELECT` permissions on that View.

Comment: ahh, so schemas are users under the hood? that's cute.

Comment: No, I am not saying that. Pre SQL Server 2005 there were no Schemas, and so the blah.ObjectName was "owner" == "blah". but starting in 2005 they added Schemas which are containers of objects. Those containers are associated with Users, but are not Users per se.

Comment: Look at the linked page for ALTER AUTHORIZATION. I believe it discusses that.